# Finding $\int \frac{\sin\sqrt{\frac{x}{2}}}{\sqrt{x\cos\sqrt{x}}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Finding $$\int \frac{\sin\sqrt{\frac{x}{2}}}{\sqrt{x\cos\sqrt{x}}}dx$$
This is a homework. I tried to solve it by assuming $x=u^2$ but after that the integrals become not simple, so I don't know how to integrate it . By which method can I solve it?

Comment: the solution contains non elementary functions

Comment: Are you sure that this "homework" is correctly typed?

Comment: @LeonAragones, yes I m sure

Comment: Hint: $$\int \frac{\sin\sqrt{{x}}}{\sqrt{x\cos\sqrt{x}}}dx = - \frac{4}{\sqrt x} \sqrt{x \cos\sqrt x}$$

Comment: but it is not the same integral

Comment: are you really sure about the $1/2$ in the $\sin$?